# c finding multiples of a number using static variables?

Tags: c, function, reference, static, static-variables

```
#include<stdio.h>

void function(void);


void main (void)
{
    int number;
    printf("call? yes(1) no(-1)");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    while(number>=0)
    {
        function();
        printf("call? yes (1) no (-1)");
        scanf("%d", &number);

    }
}


void function(void)
{
    static int multiple = 2;
    printf("%d", &multiple);
    multiple = multiple*2;

}
```

hi this is my code for finding 2 multiplied by a number . i wanted it to print out 2,4,8,16 etc. however im getting some big number when i run this code. i just started learning c so any comment is appreciated

Comment: `printf("%d", &multiple);` Remove `&` --> `printf("%d\n", multiple);`

Comment: You can use -g flag in gcc in order to debug why your getting big number. Debugging your program will help you to know what's causing the problem..by the way you don't use & printf for static int type.

Comment: Start with `gcc -Wall -Wextra` - that will help diagnose the mistake.

Answer (score 3):

In the `printf()`, the address of `multiple` is printed. Change the `printf("%d", &multiple);` to `printf("%d\n", multiple);`.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `&` from your print.

Change this:

```
printf("%d", &multiple);
```

to this:

```
printf("%d", multiple);
```

---

PS: [What should main() return in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c)

Comment: i have removed & but it is still giving me the same number. is my while statement wrong?

Comment: @andykim Have you re-built after change?